# PHP string with singlequotes for url request

Tags: php, string, url, quotes

There is some site, whitch is using odata protocol for api access.
To load users with specific status id, for example, I can use this url:

```
https://domain.com/contacts/?$filter=status_id eq 1
```

Plain and simple. In this case I'm just defining a string and getting expected response with curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$query = 'https://domain.com/contacts/?$filter=status_id eq 1'
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But the real problem starts with this:

```
https://domain.com/contacts/?$filter=email eq 'email@example.com'
```

Here email is surrounded with single quotes. I've tried both single and doublequotes string with escaping:

```
$query = 'https://domain.com/contacts/?$filter=email eq \'email@example.com\''
$query = "https://domain.com/contacts/?\$filter=email eq 'email@example.com'"
```

None of this has worked -- I've been getting request error every time.
But if I run this in ruby -- everything working as it expecteted:

```
RestClient.get "https://domain.com/contacts/?$filter=email eq 'email@example.com'", []
```

What can I do here? The version of PHP is 5.3.

Comment: What is your error? Works for me, https://eval.in/547892.. (not talking about the actual URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> https://domain.com/contacts/?$filter=email eq 'email@example.com'
> ```

This is not a valid URI. The valid URI encoded form would be:

```
https://domain.com/contacts/?%24filter=email%20eq%20'email%40example.com'
```

URLs have certain *special characters* which you cannot use directly, but which must be encoded to `%..` sequences in order to be valid. You do this in PHP by using [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode). You must encode the items *separately*:

```php
$url = 'https://domain.com/contacts/?' . rawurlencode('$filter') . '=' . rawurlencode("email eq 'email@example.com'");
```

Whether the receiving server will accept that URL or not is a different topic, but at least you're covering the basics on your end.